# C# WPF метод Main()

Tags: c#, wpf, main

Учусь работать с WPF. На старте программы нужно реализовать некую дополнительную логику. Но, к моему удивлению, в файлах проекта WPF я не нашел метода Main(). Если его нет, как компилятор определяет с чего начать программу? И тогда как мне реализовать дополнительную логику в начале программы?

> Мне нужно не OnStartUp, а именно метод Main() !!

Comment: `OnStartUp` это точка входа в приложение WPF. Если этот метод чем-то не устраивает то лучше распишите подробно чем именно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App.xaml откройте, в нем App.xaml.cs, в нем будет класс App, в котором переопределите OnStartup метод (protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)) и в нем опишите дополнительную логику перед стартом.